# Sum of integer array in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a column contains integer array like below

```
{   
    "X":[-11,-11,-11,-17],
    "Y":[184,180,184,184],
    "Z":[144,140,144,142]
}
```

I map X, Y & Z as column but I didn't get the sum by using **sum**

I tried

```
SELECT X AS items,
x_item AS (
  SELECT i AS array_items
  FROM "test_database"."quicktest", UNNEST(items) AS t(i)
)
SELECT array_items, sum(val) AS total
```

&

```
select sum(X) FROM "test_database"."quicktest"
```

It's gives me the sql error & something I missing!!.
Any comments or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance you can use reduce function:

https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html

https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html#reduce

Example code:

```
SELECT x, reduce(x, 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s) as sum_x,
y, reduce(y, 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s) as sum_y,
z, reduce(z, 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s) as sum_z
FROM example
```

Comment: Can I use cardinality(x) to get the average in same? like sum_x/cardinality(x)

Comment: Please look at the examples for reduce function.                                     SELECT reduce(ARRAY [5, 6, 10, 20], -- calculates arithmetic average: 10.25
              CAST(ROW(0.0, 0) AS ROW(sum DOUBLE, count INTEGER)),
              (s, x) -> CAST(ROW(x + s.sum, s.count + 1) AS ROW(sum DOUBLE, count INTEGER)),
              s -> IF(s.count = 0, NULL, s.sum / s.count));

Comment: I didn't check above But this is works for me    

SELECT reduce(x, 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s)/cardinality(x) FROM "test_database"."quicktest"

Comment: But some how I'm getting divisible by zero error in case [0,0,0,0,0]